# Single mysql table for private messaging

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I'm trying to create a single table for private messaging on a website. I created the following table which I think is efficient but I would really appreciate some feedback.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pm` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `subject` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User(user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I have 2 columns that determine the status of the message: `read` and `deleted`

If `read = 1`, the message has been read by the receiver. If `deleted = 1`, either the sender or the receiver deleted the message from the sent or received inbox. If `deleted = 2` both users deleted the message, therefor delete the row from the database table.

Comment: Its pretty difficult to evaluate the effectiveness of this table with so little information. MySQL is used to hold data. This table holds data. Does this table seem to be sufficient for a messaging system? Yes, it has space in it for the core necessities of a messaging system. Aside from that the utility of this implementation cannot be judged without knowing how you plan on using it, referencing it, how you're building your application, what design methodology you'll be using, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few comments:

`Charset=latin1` is going to piss some people of I'd suggest `charset=utf8`.

I'd suggest putting a foreign key check in not only on `user_id`, but on `to` as well.

Also I'd put an index on `date`, as you will be doing a lot of sorting on that field.

You need to split deleted in two fields, otherwise you will not know which user has deleted the message. (`deleted_by_user`, `deleted_by_recipient`)

Note that `date` is a reserved word and you'll need to change it into `message_date` or `` `backtick` `` it in your queries.

Comment: Thanks! Those are excellent suggestions. I would put foreign on sender and receiver to avoid duplicate messages, yes? Wouldn't adding an index on date slow down updates because the indexes need to be updated too? And updates will occur very often. That's my only concern.

Comment: @CyberJunky, Displaying messages sorted by `date` will also occur **a lot** so the extra cost of maintaining the index on insert and update will be more than offset come `select` time IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

I see that you don't have have any indexes explicitly stated. Having the appropriate indexes on your table could improve your performance significantly. I also believe that for your message column you may want to consider making i a varchar with a max size explicitly stated. Other than those two items which you may already taken care of your table looks pretty good to me.

MySQL Table Performance Guidelines:

1. Add appropriate indexes to tables. *Indexes aren't just for primary/unique keys add them to frequently referenced columns.*
2. Explicitly state maximum lengths. *Fixed length tables are faster than their counterpart*
3. Always have an id column.
4. Add NOT NULL where ever you can. *The nulls still take up space*
5. Know your data types. *Knowledge is power and can save on performance and space*

Interesting Articles:
[VarChar/TEXT Benchmarks](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,105964,105964)
[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940452/how-should-i-design-my-mysql-table-s) 
[Some Best Practices](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/)
[Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html)
The articles and some of the items I have listed may not be 100% correct or reliable so make sure you do a bit of your own research if you are interested in further tuning your performance.

Answer (score 1):

some comments:

not bad.

i would name the table something that other people might guess out of context.  so maybe private_message instead of pm.

i would be explicit on the user column names, so maybe from_user_id, and to_user_id instead of 'user_id' and 'to'

i would consider pulling out the status into a new table with status, user_id, and date - this should give you a lot more flexibility in who is doing what to the message over time.

Answer (score 1):

For displaying both the receiver's inbox and the senders outbox (and being able to delete messages respectively), you will probably need more information that what you currently have encoded. I would suggest a "deleted" field for each party. (As long as this is limited to only 1 user on each end and no broadcast messages, this works. This does not scale to broadcast messages, however, which would require more than 1 table to do efficiently)

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to enforce key relationships with `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE`:

```
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (to) REFERENCES User(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

The removal or modification of a user will propagate changes or deletions to the messages table.

Comment: Thanks! I am planning that too, wasn't sure how to exactly. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to add an column called Parent_Message_ID which will have the parent mail ID. So that replies can also included.
If you think in future to add replies to your private messages.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am considering that. However I think it would be simpler to add replies as normal messages but with <quote> tags around the original message and a `Re:` on the subject field. I think that a parent_message_id would be needed if I specifically wanted to display all my replies.

Comment: Will you be storing all the text of the question in the replies ?

Comment: Sure, like in emails. On reply, populate the textarea with the first message and the user can write his/her message above it. As an afterthought, a parent message column might be better so i won't have to re-enter text and have large values.

Comment: You can have also message type like reply,comment,reminder. These strings can be in a separate table and your primary table will have a column message_type... Based on this you can send reminders (Replies will be disabled), or allow the user to add comment,So your primary table is messages table. You have messages subject and text in a separate table,User can check the reminders... But these will be according to the functions/process you want..So added in the comments

Comment: You mean everything related to messages in one table and another table to handle what type of message each row is? That is a good idea but I would just put the "type of message" on a column in the same table with messages and just change its status accordingly.